# How to convert the given complex JSON into java Object

Tags: java, json

Need help in converting the given JSON into Java object. I am trying to use Jackson to convert it but not able to convert it successfully.
It is the response given by a third party web service.
Provide me the tips and code snippet for converting it to Java .

```
{
"result": {
    "109": [
        {
            "breached": {
                "1": "100",
                "2": "5",
                "3": "213",
                "4": "100",
                "total": "418"
            }
        },
        {
            "unhandledTicket": {
                "1": "11",
                "2": "13",
                "3": "268",
                "4": "3",
                "5": "3",
                "total": "298"
            }
        }
    ],
"110": [
        {
            "breached": {
                "1": "100",
                "2": "5",
                "3": "213",
                "4": "100",
                "total": "418"
            }
        },
        {
            "unhandledTicket": {
                "1": "11",
                "2": "13",
                "3": "268",
                "4": "3",
                "5": "3",
                "total": "298"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the code where you tried to _"convert using jackson"_ and the specific problem you faced in that.

Comment: Look at this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for convert json to java object

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object jsonData = parser.parse(jsonstring);
```

The below function for Read json data from api to String variale

```
public static String readFromApi(URL url) {

        String jsonstring;
        try {
            URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    yc.getInputStream()))) {
                jsonstring = in.readLine();
            }

            return jsonstring;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```